# Is there a callback when a session expires?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I wonder if there is any callback which fires, when the session expires (I'm using Simplelogin with `$authWithPassword()`). I searched already with google and stumbled upon this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/btaE-hCVQdk

But I don't understand how the callback of the auth-Method listens to the "Session expired" since its getting executed only once (when a user logs in). Or is there actually an event listener on its callbacks?`

I tried testing the login by using the options paramters with `expires: ((new Date()).getTime() + 1000) / 1000` (it says, it needs a timestamp in seconds not milliseconds) but I don't get a result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're look for `$onAuth`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-auth-state

Comment: I can't upvote your comment, Puf!

Comment: Thanks guys, I need to learn to take a closer look in the manual!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this:
*(in pseudo-code-steps, can help with full javascript)*.
1. get timeOffset (server/client) by doing:
1.1. on login `ref.set()` clientTime (`Date.now()`) and serverTime (`Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`) in firebase-object (i.e. online-list)
1.2. on success read both and get timeOffset in ms
2. `window.setTimeout()` with your controlled logout-function (i.e. `unauth()`) and following timeout-value:
2.2 microseconds to timeout: with login via `auth()` you get `authData.expires`, use this to calc expire-timeout-value:
`authData.expires*1000 - Date.now()+that.serverTimeOffset - 2000`

use *1000 because `authData.expires` comes in seconds.
user -2000 because you have to be faster with `unauth()` than firebase disconnects you :-)
I'm very pleased with this solution. It works perfect for my multiplayer-browser game.